# Clementine doesn't play APE files

Tags: music, gstreamer, clementine, 16.04

Clementine (1.2.3) on Ubuntu (16.04) Gnome (3.18) - doesn't play .ape files.

Before the update (from Ubuntu Gnome 15.10) it also wasn't working, but it was telling that there is a problem with gstreamer (I was reinstalling all gstreamer plugins without any result).

Now - it doesn't show any information - sometimes it even starts to play first few seconds of piece.

Comment: It seems to be an old bug with gstreamer in ubuntu: https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/3216#issuecomment-30408434 - also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/+bug/1071263

Comment: Still having this problem with Lubuntu 17.10 and Celementine 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

This seems related to [an old bug that is not fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/+bug/1071263) involving a certain version of `gstreamer` (0.10) used by Clementine  - also linked [here](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/3216#issuecomment-30408434). (I see that `ape` files can be played with Exaile 4.0.0 beta, which uses GStreamer 1.8.3.)

The most simple solution is to use another music player (Audacious, Deadbeef, etc). Most Linux audio players are not affected by this problem..

If you must use Clementine, converting to another (possibly lossless) format makes sense too, as `ape` is a lossless format. (If you have large collections in ape format with sub-folders, you may like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/547476/47206) answer, where I suggest replacing `avconv` with `ffmpeg`).

Answer (score 0):

You can install *flacon* for *.ape* files

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flacon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flacon
```

Comment: `Flacon is an open source application, written in C++ and built by using the Qt libraries, that enables the users to extract individual tracks from big audio files`. - Please give more details on how that would fix the problem of Clementine not playing ape files. - You mean we should convert the files?